# Count of date function with multiple data VBA Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I would like to set up a calculated control in a form that looks at a subform and counts the dates there. The subform has dates with multiple data in it.

Example:

```
6/10/17 99203
6/10/17 G0283
6/10/17 97014
6/13/17 G0283
6/13/17 97110
```

I would like the box to say `2`, and not `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter this code in the *OnCurrent* event of the parent form:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim DateCount As Integer
Dim LastDate As Date

Set rs = Me!YourSubformControl.Form.RecordsetClone

While Not rs.EOF
    If DateDiff("d", LastDate, rs!YourDateField.Value) <> 0 Then
        DateCount = DateCount + 1
        LastDate = rs!YourDateField.Value 
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close

Me!YourDateCountTextbox.Value = DateCount
```